# Non-trivial bound for $E[\exp(Z^2)]$ when $Z \sim {\rm Bin}(n, n^{-\beta})$ with $\beta \in (0,1)$

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, mathematical-statistics

How to find a non-trivial upper bound on $E[\exp(Z^2)]$ when $Z \sim {\rm Bin}(n, n^{-\beta})$ with $\beta \in (0,1)$? A trivial bound is obtained for substituting $Z$ with $n$.

A background on this question. In the paper by Baraud, 2002 -- Non-asymptotic minimax rates of testing in signal detection, if one is to substitute the model in Eq. (1), by a random effects model, then the above quantity appears in the computation of a lower bound.

Comment: This question is for Mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/. Seems to be a good question anyway. I remember I saw a generalization of the results in Baraud's paper done by Rozenholc an other collaborators but I can't find the paper anymore...

Comment: Do you want a lower or a upper bound? The first sentence says upper but the last sentence mentions lower.

Comment: @Srikant: you should read the mentionned paper by Barraud which is great to understand the whole thing... heuristically lower bounds are larger (testing is more difficult) when distributions (from the null and alternative) are close. Hence the upper bound asked by mkolar is related to the chi square distance between two distributions (the least favorable in the alternative and the null) if this distance is small the minimum error will be large...

Comment: @srikant an upper bound is needed here. The last sentence just states that an upper bound on the desired quantity will be used for proving the minimum error in the testing problem, as @robin explained.

Comment: Link to the paper http://math.unice.fr/~baraud/publications/min-rev1.pdf

Comment: Can you give us the hypothesis you want to test ?

Answer (score 3):

(I will delete my other non-answer, the edit of which had this nugget in it)

**No.** Asymptotically, the 'trivial' upper bound is the least upper bound. To see this, Let $P_n = P(Z = n)$. Trivially, $E[\exp{(Z^2)}] \ge P_n \exp{(n^2)} = L$, where $L$ is the lower bound of interest. Since $Z$ is binomial, we have $P_n = {n\choose n} (n^{-\beta})^n (1-n^{-\beta})^0 = n^{-n\beta}$. Then $\log{L} = -\beta n \log{n} + n^2$. It is easily shown that this is $\Omega{(n^2)}$, and thus, $L$ is $\Omega{(\exp{(n^2)})}$. Thus the trivial upper bound is, asymptotically, the least upper bound, i.e. $E[\exp{(Z^2)}] \in \Theta{(\exp{(n^2)})}$.

Comment: You're correct for the case beta = 0, but not for positive values of beta: you lost everything by throwing away the -beta*n*log(n) term.

Comment: uhh, no, not really. I assumed the OP was interested in an asymptotic (in $n$) bound. the worst case for my lower bound is $\beta = 1$. Then for, say, $n > 35$, we have $\log{n} < 0.1 n$, and thus $\log{L} = -n\log{n} + n^2 > 0.9 n^2$. Using L'Hopital's rule, you can show that $\log{L} \ge (1 - \epsilon) n^2$, asymptotically in $n$, for every $\epsilon >= 0$.

Comment: oops, should be $\epsilon > 0$; letting $\epsilon = 0$ is right out.

Comment: The point is that O(n^2) is too crude.  You obtained the next term, -beta*n*log(n), but then threw that away.  So your answer, O(exp(n^2)), is correct but it's not best.

Comment: It is not clear what kind of bound the OP is looking for. Because the free variable was given as $n$, I assume a bound asymptotic in $n$ is desired. In my answer I note that this is an asymptotic bound. (the big-O notation is another hint that this is the case.) The bound that I showed is an asymptotic *lower bound*. I am not 'throwing away' the log term: $\Omega{(n^2 - n\log{n})}$ is $\Omega{(n^2)}$. Then since this lower bound is the same as the trivial upper bound, the trivial upper bound is optimal.

Comment: @shabbychef - given that the reference provided speaks of *non-asymtotic* minimax rates... then no asymptotics should be done.  But you essentially have the answer anyway, just $L=n^{-n\beta}exp(n^{2})$.  So (+1) from me

Answer (score 2):

Numerical experiments (for 2 <= n <= 4000 and all values of beta) indicate the estimate n^2 - (n Ln(n))*beta exceeds the *logarithm* of the expectation by an amount on the order of beta*Exp(-n).  The error appears to increase monotonically in beta for each n.  This should provide some useful clues about how to proceed (for those with the time and interest).  In particular, an upper bound for the expectation exists of the form Exp(n^2 - (n Ln(n))*beta + C*Exp(-n)*beta) with C << 1.

**Update**

After staring at the summation expression for the expectation, it became evident where the nLn(n)*beta term comes from: break each binomial coefficient Comb(n,k) into its sum Comb(n-1,k) + Comb(n-1,k-1) and write Exp(k^2) = Exp((k-1)^2)*Exp(2k-1).  This decomposes the expectation e(n,beta) into the sum of two parts, one of which looks like the expectation e(n-1,beta) and the other of which is messy (because each term is multiplied by Exp(2k-1)) but can be bounded above by replacing all those exponential terms by their obvious upper bound Exp(2n-1).  (This is not too bad, because the last term with the highest exponent strongly dominates the entire sum.)  This gives a recursive inequality for the expectation,

> e(n,beta) <= (n^-beta * Exp(2n-1) + 1 - n^-beta) * e(n-1,beta)

Doing this n times creates a polynomial whose highest term is in fact Exp(n^2)*n^(-n*beta), with the remaining terms decreasing fairly rapidly.  At this point any reasonable bound on the remainder will produce an improved bound for the expectation essentially of the form suggested by the numerical experiments.  At this point you have to decide how hard you want to work to obtain a tighter upper bound; the numerical experiments suggest this additional work is not going to pay off unless you're interested in the smallest values of n.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is inspired by shabbychef's answer using the median. By definition:

$E[exp(Z^2)] = \sum_{z=1}^{z=n} exp(z^2) P(z;n,n^{-\beta})$

where,

$P(z;n,n^{-\beta})$ is the binomial probability.

Denote the [mode of this binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Mode_and_median) by: $m(n,n^{-\beta})$. Thus, by definition we have:

$P(z;n,n^{-\beta}) \le P(m(n,n^{-\beta});n,n^{-\beta}) \ \ \forall z$

Let,

$\bar{P} = P(m(n,n^{-\beta});n,n^{-\beta})$

Thus,

$E[exp(Z^2] \le \sum_{z=1}^{z=n} exp(z^2) \bar{P}$

This upper bound is a function of $n$ and $\beta$ as desired.

Hopefully, this in the right track unlike my previous attempt.

<strike>This approach is technically not ok as $Z$ is a discrete variable but can be justified if we take the normal approximation to the binomial.</strike>

I am not sure to what extent this is a better bound then the trivial bound but here is one approach. Take the [taylor series expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of $exp(z^2)$ and ignoring terms higher than the second term, you get:

$\int e^{z^2} f(z) dz < \int (1 + z^2) f(z) dz$

Now,

$\int (1 + z^2) f(z) dz = 1 + \int z^2 f(z) dz$

But, we know that:

$\int z^2 f(z) dz = Var(z) + E(z)^2$

Substituting for the variance and mean of the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) and simplifying, we get:

$\int e^{z^2} f(z) dz < 1 +  n^{1-\beta} (1-n^{-\beta} + n^{1-\beta})$

PS: Please check the math as I corrected one error.

Comment: Given that $z^2$ can be quite large, ignoring higher order terms in the Taylor expansion is pretty fishy.

Comment: hmm on second thoughts I may have my inequality reversed. The bound I computed is a lower bound and not a upper bound. Please vote it down to oblivion. :-)

Comment: by pigeonhole principle, $\bar{P} >= 1/(n+1)$, thus I think your proposed upper bound based on the mode is going to be, asymptotically, the same as the trivial upper bound.